# Get records with similar column values with pattern matching

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, psql

I have a table `cities` with records like:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 62 |
| name | Alberta |
| id | 63 |
| name | London |
| id | 64 |
| name | Canberra |

There are many more but the format is the same. I have an API in Node.js in which I receive a city name. Now, the city name can be an exact match of the `name` column or a variation of it. Like it can be 'Albarta' or 'Alberta City', etc.

Is there any way I can return this row by an SQL query without using an external service like elascticsearch or similar? I tried `like` operator but it's very limited. This query doesn't return the mentioned (and required) record:

```
select * from cities c where c."name" like 'Albarta%'
```

Comment: what sort of records does your query currently return? please add an example of the outcome.

Comment: @SiddharthSathe ofc the query i mentioned doesn't return the mentioned record, hence i asked the question. But nevertheless i added it in the edit.

Comment: You say the format is the same, but since you didn't describe the format and your example is consists of only a single member, that doesn't really tell us anything.  All your city names are 7 letters long with vowels at positions 1, 4, and 7 and also happen to the same as a Canadian province?

Comment: @jjanes i was as clear with my description as i could be. I didn't expect that level of permutations and combinations can be applied to something so simple. Anyways, city names are random. So added some more values.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look into the `SIMILAR TO` function in Postgres

```sql
SELECT 'Albarta' SIMILAR TO '%Alb(e|a)rta%'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP

> Note: You might need to adjust the `REGEX` based on the values that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soundex()`

For SQL Server:

```
with cities as
(select 1 id,'Alberta' name)
select * from cities where soundex(name)=SOUNDEX('Albarta city')
```

Soundex is a simple algorithm for comparing/normalizing English words based on phonetic similarity. PostgreSQL 8.3 and later include a soundex(text) function in the fuzzystrmatch extension.